# Dynamic array of windows, Ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am currently creating an array in C of a dynamic number of Ncurses windows.

However, windows are an "incomplete type" so their size can be variable. How can I create a variable size array of windows if `calloc` crashes when invoked with `sizeof(WINDOW)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows are referred to by variables declared as `WINDOW *` *(from the ncurses manpage)*

That is also true of arrays of Windows. You need to use an array of `WINDOW*`; even though `WINDOW` is an incomplete type, a `WINDOW*` is a complete type, and so

```
WINDOW* windows[NWINDOWS];
```

is just fine.

For a dynamic array, you will want `WINDOW** windows;`.

Comment: Works like a CHARM! Thank you.